# Ajax Call on Same JSP with Javascript

Tags: java, javascript, ajax, json, jsp

I have a JSP including three dropdown boxes called "countries","regions" and "cities". My aim is to populate regions from countries and cities from regions. I did it with parameters using Java and Javascript on same page but, in any click on dropdown lists, the page refreshes itself. I dont want it to be refreshed at everyclick on dropdown lists.

The data of "countries", "regions" and "cities" comes from JSON data on Java part "<%...%>" on same page.

I tried to do it with AJAX but couldn't find working example to pass parameters. If its required to separate the whole page into small JSPs such as "countries.jsp", "regions.jsp", "cities.jsp", I can do it but I need to solve the parameter passing between them. I would like to get the parameters as Ajax call on same page WITHOUT USING JQUERY. I need to do it with pure JS.

Im looking for your suggestions and working examples of JSP Ajax including parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I think you want to break things up into a regions.jsp and cities.jsp ( countries will always stay the same, right?). Next you need to attach a function that grabs the values from countries when it changes, using the OnChange event, and passes it to your regions.jsp. Like this:

```
<select name-"countries" id-"countries" OnChange="getRegions();"><option> ...</option></selct>
```

Then you implement javascript to make the ajax call, like this (no jquery required)

```
            var requestObj = false;

            if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
                requestObj = new XMLHttpRequest();
            } else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
                requestObj = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }

            function getRegions()
            {
                var select = document.getElementById('countries');
                var currentCountry = select.options[select.selectedIndex]; 
                if (requestObj) {
                    requestObj.open("GET", "/ajax/regions.jsp?country=" + currentCountry);
                    requestObj.onreadystatechange = function ()
                    {
                        if (requestObj.readyState == 4 && requestObj.status == 200) {
                               var options = parseJSON(requestObj.responseText);
                             for( var i=0; i<options.length; i++) { 
                                  document.getElementById("regions").appendChild("<option value='" + options['id'] + "'>" + options['text'] + "</option>");
                             }
                        }
                    }
                    requestObj.send(null);
                }
            }
```

Whew what a blast from the past with no jquery. This make sense?

Comment: What should I write exactly into "Regions.jsp" and "Cities.jsp"? How can I send and get the parameters? Will these files include html codes?

Comment: Also, may I do same operations on same page, without separating the main jsp? Thanks @frank-conry

Comment: Regions.jsp will access a GET parameter `countries` and return all the regions in that country. Cities will do the same but for Regions.

Comment: How can I pass parameter from the Main Jsp to Regions Jsp? I need to pass the Region Id to "Cities.jsp" Thanks

Comment: `var select = document.getElementById('regions');  
 var currentRegion = select.options[select.selectedIndex];` will get you the value. Then you just make the ajax call to `'cities.js?region='+currentRegion` Does that answer your question?